# Indexing multiple files in one file

Tags: java, file

I have a program that is reading from plain text files. the amount of these files can be more that 5 Million!

When I'm reading them I found them by name! the names are basically save as x and y of a matrix for example 440x300.txt

Now I want to put all of them in one big file and index them

I mean I want to now exactly for example 440x300.txt is saved in the file from which byte and end in which byte!

My first Idea was to create a separate file and save this info in that like each line contains 440 x 300 150883 173553

but finding this info will also a lot of time!

I want to know if the is a better way to find out where do they start and end!

Somehow index the files

Please help

By the way I'm programming in Java.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: what is not clear!? ask I will answer because I don't know whats missing! sorry!

Comment: *"amount of these files can be more that 5 Million!"*  Is that amount in Megabytes, number of documents, kilograms..?

Comment: Number of files! each file can be like 10-50 KB!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to read these files I would archive them in batches. e.g. use ZIP or Jar format.  This support the naming and indexing of files and you can build, update and check them using standard tools.

It is possible to place 5 million file sin one archive but using a small number of archives may be more manageable.

BTW: As the files are text, compressing them will also make them smaller. You can try this yourself by create a ZIP or JAR with say 1000 of them.

Comment: No the thing is I want to save them first and later on read them in another program! I cant archive them every time and extract when I want to read them!

Comment: You can extract them into memory, not to individual files. This would be no different to what you suggest.

Comment: My suggestion was bad thats why I'm looking for a better solution!

Comment: Its not that bad an idea. It just means lots of writing and testing. If you use software which does this already, you know that a) its been done before so its not such a bad idea b) you don't have to write/testing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to do direct addressing within your file, then you have two options:

1. Have an index at the beginning of your file so you can lookup the start/end address based on (x, y)
2. Make all records exactly the same size (in bytes) so you can easily compute the location of a record in your files.

Choosing the right option should be done based on the following criteria:

1. Do you have records for each cell in your matrix?
2. Do the matrix values change?
3. Does the matrix dimension change?
4. Can the values in the matrix have a fixed byte length (i.e. are they numbers or strings)?

Comment: No they don't have the same size of data thats why I cant do option two!

Comment: for option one the problem is reading the first lines of the file will take a lot of time also! its 5 Million!

Comment: Is there anything else please?

Comment: You don't have to read the whole file to read the index. Use RandomAccessFile to read pieces of your file

Comment: I can skip the file with that i know but how should I know that for example the info for x and y is saved in where to skip there? because because the matrix is not complete! I can have 400x400 but not 400x500

Comment: I would strongly suggest you look into a NoSQL database with this amount of data. Like MongoDB or Hadoop for example. This isn't a trivial problem to solve if you want this kind of size and good access time

Comment: thanks alot I will look into it! Just one more thing! I am going to read them later in android so i could only access sqlite which is really slow for this amount of data! do you know if NoSQL is usable in android by any chance?

Comment: It's not, but for this size of data, you'd want to have a web service to provide it anyway